# Change regex error message for Email Address in DotNetNuke 6

Tags: regex, dotnetnuke

I changed the regex for email addresses when registering to only allow people with certain domain names (ex @domain1.com or @domain2.com). Is there any way to update the error message that shows when someone enters a different domain name (ex @mysite.com)?

I checked all the resource files but couldn't find the error message "You must enter a valid email address."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@icidis is close, but you can use the Admin/Languages page which will give you access to the Language Editor and then you can update the Resources. If you modify the file directly you run the risk of losing those changes in a future upgrade. IF you use the Language Editor you can modify the RESX file specific to that Portal (based on portalid) or even at the HOST level which makes a file that applies to all portals, but doesn't change the "root" files so an upgrade doesn't overwrite them.

Check out this video in the DNN video library
http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Resources/Video-Library/Viewer/Video/232/View/Details/Introduction-to-the-DotNetNuke-Language-Module.aspx

The file you'll likely want I believe is \DesktopModules\Admin\Security\App_LocalResources\SharedResources